# Javascript singleton function not working

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to learn a bit of 'advanced' Javascript, so I figured I'd make a simple typing game.  Unfortunately, I've already gotten stuck early on, and I figure it's a stupid mistake where I am completely missing the point of something.  Here's my code:

```
var TypingTest = new function() {

    this._playing = false;

    this.Play = function() {
        this._playing = true;
    }
    this.Stop = function() {
        this._playing = false;
    }

    $(document).keydown(function(e) {
        if(this._playing) {
                    // Reference point
            console.log(e);
        }
    });
}
```

The problem is, no matter what I instantiate the `_playing` variable to, the "reference point" is never reached.  `this._playing` is always `undefined`, and I haven't the slightest clue why.  Is it scope?  Is it a protection thing?  It beats me!

EDIT: I have jQuery imported and working.  If I take out the `if` block, the game works fine.

Thank you!

Comment: Try `console.log(this);` and compare the result with what you expect. You're making wrong assumptions about what `this` refers to in your code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you are out of scope in your event, `this` in your event is referring to the document not your object. You can fix this by caching the reference to your object in a local variable `that`:

```
var TypingTest = new function() {
    ...
    var that = this;
    ...
    $(document).keydown(function(e) {
        if(that._playing) {
                    // Reference point
            console.log(e);
        }
    });
}
```